# how to restrict number of columns to be update using oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g. I want to restrict number of columns to be updated. I want to update only 300 students `Fee_Call_Opt_uid` column. Once I use `rownum < 300` it throws and error.

```
UPDATE student st
   SET st.Fee_Call_Opt_uid =
       (SELECT t.emp_id
          FROM (SELECT DISTINCT eco.emp_id, ct.city_name, con.country_name
                  FROM emp_call_opt eco
                  JOIN territory tr
                    ON tr.territory_id = eco.territory_id
                  JOIN city ct
                    ON ct.territory_id = eco.territory_id
                  JOIN country con
                    ON con.country_id = ct.country_id) t
         WHERE st.city = t.city_name
           AND st.country = t.country_name)
 WHERE st.rownum < 300
   AND st.Fee_Call_Opt_uid IS NULL;
```

SQL Error:

```
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
```

Comment: first, if the query returns more than one row, it won't work. you are updating a column in a row. second, which error are you getting ? Can you describe exactly what you want to update

Comment: Sorry I updated my question please review again

Comment: Try `WHERE rownum < 300` without alias `st.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, yes ... yet another query which raises unknown error(s).

To me, it works as expected. Simplified:

```
SQL> update student set fee_call_opt_uid = 'x' where rownum <= 10;

10 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Your turn.

---

My turn again: remove table alias from `rownum`, it causes problems (as SQL*Plus nicely points out with an asterisk):

```
SQL> update student s set s.fee_call_opt_uid = 1 where s.rownum <= 10;
update student s set s.fee_call_opt_uid = 'x' where s.rownum <= 10
                                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

SQL> update student s set s.fee_call_opt_uid = 'x' where rownum <= 10;

10 rows updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: OK, now it is much more clear. As already told, remove table alias from the ROWNUM. See my edited example.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use st.rownum . Rownum is a pseudocolumn and does not belongs to any table.