# how can i update limited number of records while update a query?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

We have update query which updates all the students record having same city_name and country but **we want to update only 500 students** have same city_name and country.

This is the query so far:

```
update student st 
set st.Fee_Call_Opt_uid = (select t.opt_uid 
                           from (select distinct eco.opt_uid
                                        , eco.employee_id
                                        , ct.city_name
                                        , con.country_name 
                                 from employee_calling_operator eco 
                                 join territory tr 
                                     on tr.territory_id = eco.territory_id
                                 join city ct 
                                     on ct.territory_id = tr.territory_id
                                 JOIN country con 
                                     on con.country_id = ct.country_id) t
                           where st.city = t.city_name 
                           and st.country = t.country_name  
                           AND st.is_active_flg = 'Y'
                           and t.opt_uid = :P242_OPT_UID);
```

Please help me out. we are using oracle 11g

Comment: Which 500 ? Last ? First ? If Last 500 then  according to which data ?

Comment: any 500 having Fee_Call_Opt_uid is null

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rownum.
Here is a simple example:

```
update test
set col1 = 2
where rownum <=2 
and col1 is null
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4bca532131122daf339dec4b1623c68)

So just add:

```
where rownum <= 500
```

Comment: what about next 500 ?
once i have 1k records and run this it only update first 500 then next i execute same query it will not because for next i have to mention rownum < 1000

Comment: @abdulraheemdev . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: I agree with @GordonLinoff, you need a new question for that new situation. Also, please try little bit harder when formating and explaining the question.

Comment: So it appears that you really want to update all of them, not just some arbitrary 500 of them.  But for some reason you seem to think you need to do it in batches of 500.  You need to explain your _real_ requirement, and why you think you need to do it in batches.

Comment: @abdulraheemdev I see you have the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63503680/how-to-restrict-number-of-columns-to-be-update-using-oracle ??